Gazebo GUI Error (Unable to create the rendering window) - ROS2 Jazzy
I am using ROS2 Jazzy on a Raspberry Pi 5.
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.01 and ROS2 Jazzy using the official instructions.
Everything ROS related works good.
But I tried installing Gazebo Harmonic sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz), and when I try to run it (gz sim shapes.sdf -v 4), I get the following error:
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301] Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1309] Unable to create the rendering window after [11] attempts.
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1191] Failed to create dummy render window.
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1192] Please see the troubleshooting page for possible fixes: https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/troubleshooting
Stack trace (most recent call last):

31 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8-gui.so.8”, at 0xffff9b86cc3f, in gz::sim::v8::gui::runGui(int&, char**, char const*, char const*, int, char const*, char const*)
30 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff988d45af, in QCoreApplication::exec()
29 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff988ca633, in QEventLoop::exec(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag)
28 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff98937c8b, in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag)
27 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0”, at 0xffff97adeb57, in g_main_context_iteration
26 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0”, at 0xffff97b42997, in
25 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0”, at 0xffff97adf89b, in
24 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff9893880b, in
23 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff988d033f, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*)
22 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff988cc47f, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
21 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5”, at 0xffff9a162aa7, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
20 Object “/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5”, at 0xffff98902aff, in QObject::event(QEvent*)
19 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so”, at 0xffff8034a5df, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderWindowItem::Ready()
18 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so”, at 0xffff8034a17f, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThread::Initializeabi:cxx11
17 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so”, at 0xffff8035b163, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThreadRhiOpenGL::Initializeabi:cxx11
16 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so”, at 0xffff8034dec7, in gz::gui::plugins::GzRenderer::Initializeabi:cxx11
15 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/libgz-rendering8.so.8”, at 0xffff802bc50b, in gz::rendering::v8::RenderEngineManager::Engine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)
14 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/libgz-rendering8.so.8”, at 0xffff802bc227, in gz::rendering::v8::RenderEngineManagerPrivate::Engine(EngineInfo, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)
13 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/libgz-rendering8.so.8”, at 0xffff802c68db, in gz::rendering::v8::BaseRenderEngine::Init()
12 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/gz-rendering-8/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so”, at 0xffff4f9f1dd7, in gz::rendering::v8::Ogre2RenderEngine::InitImpl()
11 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/gz-rendering-8/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so”, at 0xffff4f9f4af3, in gz::rendering::v8::Ogre2RenderEngine::InitAttempt()
10 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f4dc84b, in Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::initialiseAllResourceGroups(bool)
9 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f4dbd2f, in Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::parseResourceGroupScripts(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::ResourceGroup*)
8 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f528503, in Ogre::ScriptCompilerManager::parseScript(Ogre::SharedPtrOgre::DataStream&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)
7 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f51b5e3, in Ogre::ScriptCompiler::compile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)
6 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f51b2ff, in Ogre::ScriptCompiler::compile(Ogre::SharedPtr<std::__cxx11::list<Ogre::SharedPtrOgre::ConcreteNode, Ogre::STLAllocator<Ogre::SharedPtrOgre::ConcreteNode, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)
5 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f5334d3, in Ogre::MaterialTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtrOgre::AbstractNode const&)
4 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f534353, in Ogre::TechniqueTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtrOgre::AbstractNode const&)
3 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f537293, in Ogre::PassTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtrOgre::AbstractNode const&)
2 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f5a0adb, in Ogre::Technique::createPass()
1 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f49ddc7, in Ogre::Pass::Pass(Ogre::Technique*, unsigned short)
0 Object “/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3”, at 0xffff4f3cd0b0, in Ogre::Hlms::createDatablock(Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, Ogre::HlmsMacroblock const&, Ogre::HlmsBlendblock const&, std::vector<std::pair<Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator<std::pair<Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const&, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [0x220])

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?
Thank you!

I have the same issue with Framework PC with I5 CPU and Ubtuntu 24.04.

Update:
I found 2 solutions.

Solution 1 (works on Raspberry Pi):
Use Ogre 1 as render machine. No other solutions worked for me on the Raspberry (gz sim -v 3 shapes.sdf --render-engine ogre)

Solution 2: Use another computer for the simuation, not Raspberry. Raspberry does not support OpenGL version higher than 3.3, preferrably 4.3+ and that is the reason i believe is not working.


Found out more here: https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/troubleshooting/
